# How does a pandigital number check work?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I came across this solution to checking if a number is pandigital(an n-digit number that makes use of all the digits 1 to n exactly once, eg.1234).

```
private boolean isPandigital(int n){
    int digits = 0;
    int numDigits = String.valueOf(n).length();
    for (; n > 0; n /= 10){
        digits += (1 << (n - ((n / 10) * 10) - 1));
    }
    return digits == ((1 << numDigits) - 1);
}
```

The for loop takes a digit off n each loop(1234,123,12,1). Inside the loop:

```
(n - ((n / 10) * 10) - 1)
```

evalutes to the last digit of n and takes away 1.

I understand what the method is physically doing but what property of pandigital numbers is it exploiting?

Comment: `(n - ((n / 10) * 10)` is a very awkward way of writing `n % 10`

Comment: why the C# tag? neither `boolean` nor `String.valueOf` is recongized by the C# compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property it's exploiting is that for a pandigital input of length n, summing the digits must equal (n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) ... + 1) which is equivalent to (n * (n + 1)) / 2.  But instead of doing the algorithm in decimal the function is doing it with binary bits.

It uses each decimal digit to increment a binary digit.  For a decimal digit d the binary bit at (d - 1) gets incremented.  i.e. the decimal digit 3 becomes (1 << (3 - 1)) which will increment the 2nd binary digit.  These are summed and compared to the expected value.  The expected value is that every binary digit will be set for the length of your input.  If your input is 1234 every binary bit will be set for a 4 bit binary value (1111 in binary = 15 in decimal from `((1 << numDigits) - 1)`).

Answer (score 0):

No specific property is used.

The trick is that when you find a digit i, you add (2 to the power i) to the variable digits, i.e setting a single bit in this integer. At the end of the process, number of n digits wiil be pandigital, if digits = (2 to the power i) -1, i.e. the n low bits of digits all set to 1.

*Just for fun, you may do it in a recursive way*:

```
bool ispandigital = testpandigital(n.ToString()) ;

private bool testpandigital(string nbr)
{
  string digit=str.Length.ToString() ;
  return nbr=="0" || (nbr.Contains(digit) && testpandigital(nbr.Replace(digit,"")) ;  
}
```

Comment: " but what property of pandigital numbers is it exploiting?".... though I like the recursion...

Comment: @MongZhu: No specific property is used. The trick is that when you find a digit *i*, you add *(2 to the power i)* to the variable *digits*, i.e setting a single bit in this integer. At the end of the process, number of *n* digits wiil be pandigital, if *digits* =   *(2 to the power i) -1*, i.e. the n low bits of *digits* all set to 1.

Comment: I have the feeling that this belongs in your post, since it sounds exactly what opp is asking for. So the property would be the binary representation :)